# I cannot make up my mind: "at the moment" has the same meaning than "At this moment"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Example: The police arrived and the police chief says: I want to know if there is anybody in the house at the moment!! or..at this moment?

Comment: More than one exclamation or question mark is an error.

Comment: I don´t get it Michael, what´s the error?  I know I could say: "right now" but I would like to know if the sentence would mean exactly the same thing whether I use "At the moment" or "At this moment". Thanks.

Comment: I suggest *The police chief demands: "I want to know if there is anybody in the house!"* Why does "at the moment" even need to be in the sentence? It doesn't mean any other time but **now**. Don't get confused by making sentences more complicated than they need be.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference is emphasis.

In the example sentence, exchanging 'at the moment' for 'at this moment' will shift the emphasis to the time, 'THIS moment', making it a more important part of the message that he wants to know if there's someone in right now. I'd actually rephrase the sentence to 'right now!' instead of 'at the/this moment!', it gives more energy to the message in my opinion.

Comment: There could be an ambiguity: does the officer want to know right now? Can he wait 5 minutes so someone can go and check out the house?

Comment: @weather vane: good point...

Answer (score 0):

"At this moment" is an idiom, at least in the U.S., which is an emphatic way to say "now." It is a bit formal, and perhaps the answer saying that "right now" is even more emphatic is correct.

"At the moment" is a grammatical construction and, in certain cases, an appropriate and idiomatic one, but it is seldom if ever used as a synonym for "now," at least not in the U.S. Thus, in this context, "at the moment" does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Example: The police arrived and the police chief says: I want to know if there is anybody in the house at the moment!! or..at this moment?

at the moment = now = right now

Generally, in speech, we'd use **at the moment**  in your sentence.

It sounds more idiomatic. At this moment, though, is not a mistake. A native speaker just would not use it here.